# Javascript add key & value from one object to another based on regex condition

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, google-api

Problem: Trying to find how much website traffic we are getting from each partner via combining output objects from 2 apis.

The thought is to take the crm objects, look up their website pageview values from the analytics api object (using regex match example1.com.*) and add the pageview property and value to the respective crm object.

This is a node.js app.

CRM API Object (Leads from CRM)
api key / value

```
[ CollectionItem {
    '0695dw9946': null,
    fc0b0dw9437: 'example1.com',
    adf03dw9241: null
  CollectionItem {
    '095ab5946': null,
    f0b0b8643: 'example2.com',
    af03bf024: null
 }]
```

Analytics Object (Website Pageviews by Traffic ga:sourceMedium)

```
data:
{ kind: 'analytics#gaData',
 id:
  'https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga:&dimensions=ga:sourceMedium&metrics=ga:pageviews&start-date=30daysAgo&end-date=today',
 query:
  { 'start-date': '30daysAgo',
    'end-date': 'today',
    ids: 'ga:',
    dimensions: 'ga:sourceMedium',
    metrics: [Array],
    'start-index': 1,
    'max-results': 1000 },
 totalsForAllResults: { 'ga:pageviews': '7450' },
 rows:
[ [ 'example2.com / referral', '7350' ], //pageviews from partner 2
['example1.com / referral', '100' ] ] //pageviews from partner 1
}}
```

Desired Combined Output:

```
    [ CollectionItem {
    '0695dw9946': null,
    fc0b0dw9437: 'example1.com',
    websitepageviews: '100',
    adf03dw9241: null
  CollectionItem {
    '095ab5946': null,
    f0b0b8643: 'example2.com',
    websitepageviews: '7350',
    af03bf024: null
 }]
```

Update:
I've been trying things along the lines of this... (I am not sure I'm on the right path at all).

```
let obj1 = CRMobject;
let obj2 = ANALYTICSobject;
var count = Object.keys(CRMobject).length;
var newarray = [];
var i = 0;

Object.keys(obj1).forEach(function(partner){
    // if partner website found in analytics object...
    let newarray[i] = Object.assign({}, obj1, obj2.data.rows) //needs to be rows[something]
    i++;
});
```

Comment: What, if anything, have *you* tried?  What problems did you have with your attempt?

Comment: I've tried a few things, I don't think I'm even close.  I'm thinking something along the lines of: let obj1 = CRMobject;
 let obj2 = ANALYTICSobject;
 count = Object.keys(CRMobject).length;
 var newarray = [];
 var i = 0;

 Object.keys(obj1).forEach(function(partner){

 //if match...
 let newarray[i] = Object.assign({}, obj1, obj2.data.rows)

 });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a rough go at what you're looking for. I see you added some of the things that you've tried, it's usually helpful to explain where you think the problem is and why what you've tried isn't working. Note that in the example below I'm using some advanced features that may not be supported in all browsers, like `Object.values()`. Also, you'll want to find a better regex to match your URL, I wouldn't recommend that in any type of production code, but it works for the example. URL regex's are all over on the web, and are far more robust than this.

```js
const crms = [{
    '0695dw9946': null,
    fc0b0dw9437: 'example1.com',
    adf03dw9241: null
  },
  {
    '095ab5946': null,
    f0b0b8643: 'example2.com',
    af03bf024: null
  }
];

const analytics = {
  data: {
    kind: 'analytics#gaData',
    id: 'https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga:&dimensions=ga:sourceMedium&metrics=ga:pageviews&start-date=30daysAgo&end-date=today',
    query: {
      'start-date': '30daysAgo',
      'end-date': 'today',
      ids: 'ga:',
      dimensions: 'ga:sourceMedium',
      metrics: [Array],
      'start-index': 1,
      'max-results': 1000
    },
    totalsForAllResults: {
      'ga:pageviews': '7450'
    },
    rows: [
      ['example2.com / referral', '7350'], //pageviews from partner 2
      ['example1.com / referral', '100']
    ] //pageviews from partner 1
  }
};

const poorUrlRegex = /([http|https]:\/\/)?.*/;
const results = crms.map(crm => {
  const result = Object.assign({}, crm);
  result.websitepageviews = -1
  const vals = Object.values(crm).filter(v => !!v);
  const url = vals.find(v => !!v.match(poorUrlRegex));
  if (url) {
    const matchingRow = analytics.data.rows.find(r => r[0].indexOf(url) > -1);
    if (!!matchingRow) result.websitepageviews = parseInt(matchingRow[1], 10);
  }

  return result;
});
console.log(results);
```

I named your example data and then used `Array.prototype.map` to add the page views. This does an operation on each array element and returns the modified element. The `Object.assign` is there to not modify the existing data. `Object.values` works just like `Object.keys`, but on the values. I'm using the `Array.prototype.find` to find URL-like values, then I try to find a matching row in your analytics data.

This is also making a lot of assumptions, like this will only find *one* matching row in your analytics data, if the url appears more than once, it will not add the page views only return the first occurrence. It also is lacking any type of error handling, but will return a `-1` if it doesn't find a matching URL in the analytics.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to help and provide feedback on using stack. I've taken 2 online node/express/mongo courses that taught how to build basic CMS systems - not enough background to solve some of these tasks.  I registered for 2 JS courses today to try to build vocabulary and understanding of tools available. I'll look into regex solutions based on your comments. This is for internal marketing use by 2 people to quickly and easily check partner performance, with additional features like conversions to come later.